# A question in Quantum Phase Transition of Transverse Ising Model

Tags: quantum-spin, phase-transition, ising-model

In section 1.4 quantum Ising model  of Subir Sachdev's book Quantum Phase Transitions, he discusses the quantum phase transition of transverse quantum Ising Model at zero temperature (so we just focus on the ground state):
$$H=-J g \Sigma_{i}\sigma_{i}^x-J \Sigma_{<ij>}\sigma_{i}^z\sigma_{j}^z$$

In the limit of $g$->0, the  spin-spin correlation function behaves as follows:
$$\lim_{|x_{i}-x_{j}|->\infty}<0|\sigma_{i}^z\sigma_{j}^z|0>=N_{0}^2$$
where $N_{0}$  is a function of $g$ and $N_{0}(g=0)=1$.

In the limit of $g$-> $\infty$, the correlation function decades exponentially:
$$<0|\sigma_{i}^z\sigma_{j}^z|0>~e^{-|x_i-x_j|/\eta}$$.

From above two limit cases, the author claims that: it's not possible for states that have the above two behaviors to transform into each other analytically as a function of g, thus there must exists a quantum critical point $g_c$ .

**My question is** that it's hard for me to accept his claim in a very comfortable way. I really doubt the mathematical rigor of his claim that "it's not possible... ".  I think we have much freedom  to came up with a function with above limit. Can someone help make his claim more rigor, even little hint would help.